# How to get input data from text box in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have this piece of HTML(JSP) code to input phone number !! on which JQuery has been applied to check the validity of input text by user.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" value="" id="phone" autocomplete="off" name="mobileNumberField" class="a-input-text a-width-medium a-spacing-small textbox" data-ng-model="mobile_number.value " data-ng-required="true" required="required" placeholder="mobile_number.value_def">
```

So suppose text in input box is +91 9056 6783 32

when i print data in controller using $scope.mobile_number.value 
sometimes i get output like :
undefined or 
+91 or
+91 9056

i don't get complete input text !!
How to i get complete input text in controller??

Comment: I know but i want to get data using ng-model

Comment: You seem to define it as "mobile_number.value" but use it as "mobile_number_value"

Comment: How can we tell what's inside your controller? Paste it please.

Comment: @sureshKoya typo mistake in question

Comment: @Keanmoort controller code is irrelavent

Comment: How does mobile_number object look? Is it initialized somewhere? You're referring to a property `value` from object `mobile_number`, so that's why I asked about the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller you can first declare an object
`$scope.mobile_number={}`

```
    mainApp.controller('testApp', function($scope) {
               $scope.mobile_number={};
               $scope.mobile_number.value ="";
               $scope.$watch('mobile_number.value', function() {
               // do something here
               console.log($scope.mobile_number.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your number as `long` datatype, rather than using a string.

To correctly display phone numbers in human-readable format, make use of [angular-input-masks](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks).  The project is under MIT license.  So feel free to modify the format to your liking.

Plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/p3yFhsNwRO0v4kC915xF?p=preview

Dependency inject `ui.utils.masks` to your project.

**Javscript:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.utils.masks']);
```

**HTML:**

```
<input ui-us-phone-number type="text" ng-model="myPhoneNumber" />
```

Comment: does adding this dependeny well define $scope.mobile_number.value to long type or i still need to do something ??

Answer (score 0):

i tried the similar code but didnot get any issue .I am getting the complete number in controller.